# Calculating modulus by recursion without using modulo division

Tags: c++, function, recursion, modulus

I'm doing a problem with recursive functions for a class project.  I'm trying to write a program that uses a recursive function that calculates a modulus without actually using the modulus operator.  I'm trying to use a reference parameter because I think that's the easiest way to do this, however my program is not functioning as intended.

```
//Michael Hery
//COP 2001
//11/15/2017
//Recursive Modulus

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int recursiveMod(int &, int);

int main()
{
    int num;
    int den;
    int displayNum;
    int total;

    cout << "Please input the numerator (an integer) >> ";
    cin >> num;
    while (num < 0)
    {
        cout << "Integer must be greater than or equal to zero. >> ";
        cin >> num;
    }
    displayNum = num;
    cout << "Please input the denominator (an integer) >> ";
    cin >> den;
    while (den <= 0)
    {
        cout << "Integer must be greater than zero. >> ";
        cin >> den;
    }
    cout << "You have entered " << num << " % " << den << endl;

    total = recursiveMod(num, den);

    cout << "Modulus result: " << displayNum << " % " << den << " = " << total << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

int recursiveMod(int &num, int den)
{
    if (num == 0)
        return 0;

    num = num - den;

    if ((num - den) > den)
    {
        recursiveMod(num, den);
    }
    return num;
}
```

Comment: "not functioning as intended" how? Give us an example input and output that causes the misbehaving (a [mcve]).

Comment: You're calling `recursiveMod(num, den);` in the recursion, but ignore the result. What you probably wanted is just `return recursiveMod(num, den);` without the whole if statement.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [the help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to see how to use the site and ask a good question.

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors with your code. Firstly you need to include cstdlib for system("pause") to work.

```
#include <cstdlib>
```

Secondly, in your

```
int recusive mod(int &num, int den)
```

the condition should be num > den and return must be put.

```
if (num > den)
    {
        return recursiveMod(num, den);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
 if ((num - den) > den)
```

For example, if num is 4 and den is 3, then 4-3 is 1 and 1 is not greater than 3, so you will return 4. What you want is

```
 if (num > den)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int recursiveMod(int num, int den)
{
    if (num < 0) return recursiveMod(num + den, den);

    // Don't forget the case of num = 2 and den = 7
    if (num < den) return num;

    return recursiveMod(num - den, den);
}
```

Comment: you dont need a pointer here you only have to process it by value

Comment: What about `recursiveMod( -7, 3 )` ?

Comment: @Sheljohn try reading his main method he's forcing a positive inputs

Comment: This is bad practice; if you propose a solution, then either your solution enforces validity constraints on its own (eg in this case, declaring input types as `unsigned`), or provides an implementation consistent with the specified input types (ie, handling the negative cases). As it stands, your answer is incorrect, and in any case, it requires further explanations.

Comment: negative case added @Sheljohn didn't know that there was a mathematical rule for negative modulos, now is perfect.